# Weaving\Sewing\Zipping two sets of data

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for some help.  Initially I had two data sets that I strung together in order of rows using this `TEXTJOIN(" > ", true, Roster!D29:D44)`.  Now, I need to change it up where the two sets of data are zipped together.  I can't find any functions that would do this and have no idea how to easily do this so I turn to you guys for help.  Here is a picture of the output I am trying to achieve.  Thanks in advance for the help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" > ", TRUE, FILTER(SORT(A1:A11,B1:B11,TRUE),SORT(B1:B11,1,TRUE)<>""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" > ", 1, FLATTEN({A2:A5, A8:A11}))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`=TEXTJOIN(" > ",TRUE,SORTBY(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),FILTER(B:B,B:B<>"")))`

You need to have office 365 to use sortby and filter.